# SED: How to remove special characters before the numbers?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have the following string:

```
E E E 11 5 E 3 4
```

I need to be able to strip all "E" characters that go before the numbers. So that the output would be like this:

```
11 5 E 3 4
```

The number of first "E" can be different, so it can be either "E E" or "E E E E" etc.
How can I do it with SED? If possible, with alternative shell utils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/^[E ]*\([0-9]\)/\1/'
```

This will replace all E's and spaces before the first digit on a line, and that first digit, with the first digit.

The caveat would be that this doesn't work on lines consisting *only* of E's and spaces; I assumed from the wording that the removal is to be done only if there are numbers on the line. To support the case with only E's simply use `s/^[E ]*//` for the program.

Answer (score 0):

Found another variant:

```
sed 's/^[E ]\+//g'
```